# How to get value in array with delimeter in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have already stored data in array and I want to get value in each id that separated with ","

Example:

sql table:

```
ruleID | symptomID | penyakit
R1     |  s1,s2    | DD
R2     |  s1,s2,s3 | DD
```

Php code:-

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $allS = $row['symptomID'];
    $penyakit = $row['penyakit'];

    if ($penyakit == 'DD') {
        $arrRuleDenggi[] = $allS;
    }
}
```

I've already tried `print_r(explode(",",$arrRuleDenggi)` but it doesn't work.I just wanna take value without commas..

Comment: what is your expected output .

Comment: Please post your code, it's hard to help without being able to see what you're doing exactly.

Comment: `$arraySymp[]=array([0]=>s1,s2 [1]=>s1,s2,s3)` it will create you  a two dinesional array., does this right

Comment: add your code bro for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: You need to loop the array and then apply the explode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is

```
 $arraySymp = array(0=>"s1,s2", 1=>"s1,s2,s3");
```

you can

```
foreach($arraySymp as $inner)
    foreach(explode(",", $inner) as $inner_inner)
        echo $inner_inner."\n";
```

See [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b11c56e8ef0d274ab7e7adf91c10cb1f2b57a0c7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the array and then apply the explode like below

```
foreach($arrRuleDenggi as $key=>$val){

  print_r(explode(",",$val);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode` don't takes array , its takes string and split that string into array [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

what you want is something like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $allS = $row['symptomID'];
    $penyakit = $row['penyakit'];

    if (strcmp($penyakit , 'DD') == 0) {
        $arrRuleDenggi[] = explode(',' , $allS);
    }
}

print_r(arrRuleDenggi);
```